# Are there physics, theories that predict standing wave harmonic deviations in curved tubes?

Tags: waves, acoustics, reflection, resonance, harmonics

For cylinders, it's widely documented how to predict the harmonic frequencies given the length of the tube, the end conditions and the speed of sound which is in turn determined by what gas is in the cylinder and at what temperature.

This principle of standing wave harmonics, resonance seems to be always illustrated, discussed in terms of *straight* tubes.

I suppose the tube doesn't necessarily have to be straight, that standing waves can still be excited, but also guess there is some limitation to how much curvature can be tolerated before the harmonics shift in frequency or become distorted in some manner.

> Are there physics, theory that can address such deviations; equations
>   that take into account curvature?

I would further venture to guess something similar to what light does in a fiber - total internal reflections and the like.

Comment: Are you, in effect, asking how an instrument such as a saxophone,  with  an upturned bell, still produces it's distinctive sound (in a very, very harmonious way :) This is related,  but apologies  if it is not relevant : http://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/saxacoustics.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This paper by Felix and Delmont (2012) may be helpful](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/643184/filename/Felix_Nederveen_Dalmont_2011_JAcoustSocAm_submitted.pdf).

The authors refer to a second paper which show that curved ducts have a lower inertance than their straight counterparts,

$$\mathcal{L}_{bend} = \alpha \ \mathcal{L}_{straight}$$

where

$$\alpha = \frac{\frac{1}{2} \kappa^2}{1 - \sqrt{1 - \kappa^2}}$$

with $\kappa = a/R_{0}$ describing the curvature as follows:

[image]

In the paper they outline a theoretical approach and test against experiment.